# How to do datetime arithmetic in MQL5?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I want to calculate how much time has been passed since my last trade.

I have `datetime lastExitTime;`.

How to subtract from "now" this lastExitTime to get the difference in **milliseconds**?

Is there something like `lastExitTime.toUnixTimestamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values of type `datetime` are already in Unix Timestamp format (seconds ellapsed since January 1st, 1970). Therefore use either `TimeLocal()-lastExitTime` or `TimeCurrent()-lastExitTime` to find the number of seconds since your last trade.

Comment: Thank you @PaulB! Can I get milliseconds precision somehow?

Comment: It is possible, you would have to use `uint  GetTickCount();`. You can see the documentation here: [link](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/common/gettickcount)

Comment: "The GetTickCount() function returns the number of milliseconds that elapsed since the system start." - so you mean to manually measure the time on event, I see.
"Time is stored as an unsigned integer, so it's overfilled every 49.7 days if a computer works uninterruptedly."